# Trigger a property from a component from other's component event in blazor

Tags: blazor

I have the following parent razor component which is main table and it is splitted in small components:

```
<div class="row">
    <TopSection DeleteCss="@deleteCssStyle" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div>
            <a href="" class="fs-4 fw-bold">
                <span class="oi oi-loop-circular text-black rotate-45"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="" class="fs-4 fw-bold">
                <span class="oi oi-account-logout text-black rotate-180"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-11">
        <div class="table-responsive" id="pay-table">
            <table class="table table-striped table-borderless">
                <TableHeader ... />
                <TableBody Items="@filteredList" OnCheckRow="@OnCheckRow" />
                <TableFooter ... />
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `TopSection`:

```
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Edit</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn">Add</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn @DeleteCss">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
[Parameter]
public string DeleteCss { get; set; } = "disabled";
```

The main `OnCheckRow`:

```
protected void OnCheckRow(int checkedRows)
{
    deleteCssStyle = checkedRows > 0 ? "" : "disabled";
}
```

The `TableBody`

```
<tbody>
    @{
        foreach (var row in Items)
        {
            <tr @onclick="@((e)=> OnCheck(row) )">
                <td>
                    <EditForm Model="@row" class="form-check-inline">
                        <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@row.IsChecked" id="@row.Id" />
                    </EditForm>
                    @row.Title
                </td>
                ...
                ...
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

and code behind:

```
[Parameter]
public Action<int> OnCheckRow { get; set; } = (i) => { };

protected void OnCheck(MyItem row)
{
     row.IsChecked = !row.IsChecked;
     OnCheckRow?.Invoke(Items.Count(s => s.IsChecked));
}
```

So, I want when check at least one item, I want Delete button to be available otherwise add class "disabled" to avoid click on it

Seems when trigger click, the property for deleteCssStyle is not updated as well in `TopAction` component and the Delete button still is disabled.

I'm lost here. I'd like a help here.

**LATER EDIT / RESOLUTION**

I have to use EventCallback  instead of Action for OnCheckRow

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<int> OnCheckRow { get; set; }

protected async Task OnCheck(PayComponentListItem row)
{    row.IsChecked = !row.IsChecked;
     await OnCheckRow.InvokeAsync(Items.Count(s => s.IsChecked));}
```

and will work like a charm !

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution, you can test it using LINQ

```
protected void OnCheckRow(int checkedRows)
{
   deleteCssStyle = Items.Any(x=> x.Ischecked) ? "" : "disabled;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not at OnCheckRow, I get right style, but `DeleteCss` property is not triggered anymore, just for first time at initialization

Comment: Put a breakpoint in OnCheckRow and examine value of deleteCssStyle, also check declaration of deleteCssStyle

Comment: It seems that events are not fired, try this code <InputCheckbox Value="@row.IsChecked" ValueChanged=(e=>OnCheck(row)) id="@row.Id" />

Comment: @SnakeEyes .Also don't forget to set row.Ischecked before calling Oncheck